# SQLServer - Creating well formed XML with For XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, file, sql-server-2016

I am trying to generate a large .XML file from the table data in SQL Server. But i am getting the well-formed error when i try to parse it on the .NET side.

SQL Code :-

```
Select TOP 300000 
        PID as ID,              
        Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(EFSNameLine1,10,30))),'&','') as NameLine1,              
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EFSNameLine2)) as NameLine2,            
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EFSCity)) as City,              
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EFSState)) as [State],
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EFSZip)) as ZipCode,            
        DateUpdated as DateUpdated
From dbo.partner as Contact with(nolock)    
ORDER by PID DESC   
FOR XML Auto, Root('CustomerData')
```

Then i am saving the output from the Sql Server management studio result window to the external XML file. The file size is high and around 60 Meg.

But when i try to parse the XML data into the dataset, i get the exception of not well-formed xml error.

```
   var xmlfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "customer-sample-data.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("XML File path >>>> " + xmlfilePath);

        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        objDataSet.ReadXml(xmlfilePath);

        if (objDataSet != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data obj is ready !");
        }
```

[image]

Please suggest how to produce the large data XML file from the SQL Server Management Studio tool. My requirement is to prepare the sample XML data for the consumption by another application for some testing.

Comment: Did you have a look at "Line 6 Pos 1" ? The message sounds to me like there is an unexpected newline in the xml or something like this.

Comment: But i am generating the XML with the SQL Query and it should be well-formed. I want to know, if i am missing something in creating the well-formed xml from management studio

Comment: Off-topic and perhaps not a problem for your code; [no lock](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) can lead to missing and duplicated records, among other things.  Back on-topic; can you include a sample of the XML?  Perhaps one that includes line 6?

Comment: Have you tried using `Results to File` for the query results instead of `Results to Grid` and then saving to a file?

Comment: @digital.aaron I think that could be the resolution to my problem. I will try with that option.

Comment: I tried even results to file does not push the complete output into the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as posted originally, had a comma in the wrong place... I assume you've modified this for brevity (a good idea). This statement would not work at all (syntax error).

I edited your question to

```
Select TOP 300000 
        PID as ID,              
        Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(EFSNameLine1,10,30))),'&','') as NameLine1,              
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EFSNameLine2)) as NameLine2,            
        --more columns here
        From dbo.partner as Contact with(nolock)    
        ORDER by PID DESC   
        FOR XML Auto, Root('CustomerData')
```

First of all: There is no need to think about the `&` character (if there is no other reason to replace this)! `FOR XML` will implicitly escape all forbidden characters:

```
SELECT 'This <> is & forbidden!' FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('test')
```

Will produce this - completely XML-safe - output:

```
<test>
    <row>This &lt;&gt; is &amp; forbidden!</row>
</test>
```

And secondly: Any XML generated with `FOR XML` will be - for sure! - a valid XML. Ohterwise you'd get an exception while running your statement. The error you get is - very probably - not bound to an invaid XML.

Some things with `FOR XML AUTO`: If your column names might be *strange* somehow, this can lead to some unexpected element names:

```
--Name with blank,  
--Name with quotes,  
--blank only,  
--Name with forbidden chararacters,  
--Name inlcudes a line break!
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Strange Name] INT
                  ,[Other'Strange"Name] INT
                  ,[ ] INT
                  ,[Silly<&>] INT
                  ,[With a 
Line Break] INT); 
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,1,1,1,1);
SELECT * FROM @tbl; --Working "normally"

SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('test');
```

Leads to

```
<test>
  <_x0040_tbl Strange_x0020_Name="1" Other_x0027_Strange_x0022_Name="1" _x0020_="1" Silly_x003C__x0026__x003E_="1" With_x0020_a_x0020__x000D__x000A__x0009_Line_x0020_Break="1" />
</test>
```

The excpetion message points to line 6, Pos 1. *Pos 1* might point to a `new line` in the wrong place. The `"ode'` might be connected to the `ZipCode`?

Try to open your XML within an editor and check for errors...

Maybe you are using a variable to small for the whole content somewhere in between the generation and the write-out? This might cut the XML before it ends...

Alltogether I'd advise to use `FOR XML PATH()` in all cases, with `AUTO` you never no exactly what happens behind the scenes. `PATH` allows you to control the output and format much better.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to generate it from SQL server and not from code. What you need to do is return your row collection from sql server and then generate xml in your code. Below is the sample code which we use to generate xml from collection of rows.

```
public static class SerializationHelper
    {
        public static bool Serialize<T>(T value, out string serializedXml) where T : class
        {
            serializedXml = string.Empty;
            if (value == null)
                return false;

            try
            {
                using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                    serializedXml = writer.ToString();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static string ToXml<T>(T value) where T : class
        {
            string result;
            Serialize(value, out result);
            return result;
        }

        public static T FromXml<T>(string xml) where T : class
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var reader = new StringReader(xml);
            var obj = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return obj as T;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use same class something like below.

**string xml = SerializationHelper.ToXml(items);**

For our purpose we are returning generated xml as a string but in your case you case return xml.

Note : Please use xml annotation in your class which you are passing to the above method.

**------------------ EDIT : XML from sql and parsing in c# --------------**

As per your comments, if you would like to generate it from sql and parse it in c# then you can do something like below.

Here is query which return xml.

```
select Item1, Item2, Item3 from myTable for Xml RAW('myitem'),elements XSINIL,root('root')
```

This is how my class will look like for serialization.

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "myitem")]
    public class Myitem
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item1")]
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item2")]
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item3")]
        public string Item3 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "myitem")]
        public List<Myitem> Myitem { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I can call above same helper method like below to generate collection.

```
var result = await db.GetData();//string xml 

var response = SerializationHelper.FromXml<Root>(result);
```

Comment: I cannot generate the XML data from the code because it will be used for some testing by another team.

Comment: In that case why they cann't use same xml parsing at their end.

Comment: Because the other team does not have access to the DB